# What does the graph 'Short circuit monitoring interval Vs time' mean in this SSR data sheet?

Tags: switches, relay, protection, circuit-protection, solid-state-relay

In one of the Panasonic Solid State Relay (SSR) [datasheet](https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/519),the short circuit behaviour is as shown below :

If short detected- > Trip the relay -> Periodically retry untill the fault is cleared.

[image]

I find 2 graphs- mentioning the details of above behaviour.

1. Graph 13 :Looks reasonable- Higher the short-circuit current faster the detection ( lower the time it is permitted to flow before the relay is tripped).

[image]

**2. Graph 14  : I have no clue what it means wrt the short circuit beviour!!**

[image]